# How can i use javascript to scroll this page to the end?

Tags: javascript

I want to reach the bottom of this website, but i do not have the time to do it. http://thedeepestsite.com/

BTW, this is an awesome ad stunt!

Comment: posible duplicate [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318129/javascript-on-scroll-to-end?rq=1)

Comment: you could add an anchor at the bottom of the page

Comment: on closer inspection, I don't think that would work. Can you find a way to increase the speed limit?

Comment: Not really a coding issue I don't think. How about changing the speed of your mouse wheel (Control Panel if you're using Windows)

Comment: There is a fixed speed limit of 60cm/sec - need to find the variable that holds this limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`window.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.scrollTo):

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

If you want jQuery, [there's a nice plugin for this](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) as well by the same name.